# Is there a way to access a root level variable in a module?

Tags: terraform

I have a root level variable, whose value is set at run time via a tfvar file. The tfvar file used and the var value can vary. Now I want to use this variable inside a module, the terraform way to do this is to set it up as a module variable and pass the root var when creating the module.

Except, I have this module used in our infrastructure several hundred times. Is repeating this variable 100s of times the only way to do this? Can the module access root namespace to grab the variable value?

I'm half tempted to use an external data script in the module to fetch the value instead, except, I wont know which tfvars file will be in effect at runtime..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only Terraform supported way is to pass the value into the module as a variable. Terraform has made me a copy/paste expert.

The only other approach that comes to mind that Terraform supports is making creative use of the [External Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html).

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned external data in my question. That's a bit tricky as well in my scenario because terraform wont tell me which tfvars file was passed in at command launch.